# Removing sensitive data from Git. “fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm'”

Tags: git

I'm trying to run this command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.js' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing single quotes with double quotes, as this may help with some console shells
*e.g.*:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.js" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```